# Get the heading number at my Current selection

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have tried Everything I could find to get just the heading number for the Selection in Microsoft Word.

What I tried.

```
Selection.HomeKey wdline, wdExtend
Selection.Expand wdline
Selection.HomeKey wdParagraph, wdExtend
ect. Simular stuff.
```

Example of the heading.

```
4.2.3     This is a heading
```

Everything I try just gives me the text in the heading and not the number

I want it to return

```
4.2.3
```

I cant convert the Documents Number to Text because it will mess with the spacing.

Comment: show the code you already have and state in tags which application you refer to?

Comment: If you've "tried Everything", surely you must be able to include at least one of those things you tried here in your question, right? Please [edit] to do so. Thanks. (Also, `vba` != `vbscript`; even though they're similar in name, they are not the same language. `VBA` is "Visual Basic for Applications", which is used in MS Office products. `VBS` is "Visual Basic Scripting", which is part of the Windows operating system. Use the tag that is appropriate to the language you're using, please.)

Comment: I said Vba because I can convert vba to Vbs.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have solved my issue by using.

```
Selection.Paragraphs(1).Range.ListFormat.ListString
```

This gave me just the number.

Why a heading is a Paragraph??? I just don't know.

Comment: it's quite simple- every section of document with a 'line-break' at the end is a paragraph.

Comment: But I don't understand, instead, how to get the internal reference number associated to the title number.

Comment: Nice one, just what I was after. Took me a while to realise that the reason it didn't initially work was that the document I was reviewing had manually numbered paragraphs :-)

Answer (score 2):

I had to deal with parsing of Word documents lately and needed to get headings numbers, found out paragraphs for Word increases after every line break.

I made a script that parses word document & builds an array with:
- text of the heading
- paragraph number (as word understands it)
- heading depth
- reconctructed heading number

You can query with **parGetStr** giving a paragraph number as param, the macro will return the heading number from the paragraph num given (***ANSWERING THE FORMER QUESTION***).

**parErase** will erase the table (needed if you made changes to the word headings and want to update the table as the array content is build only once when you use **parGetStr**).

**parDraw** is not really needed unless you want to show the table in a new document (for debug purposes for example) and rely on other scripts you would have to get (on my github too).

You can find the latest scripts versions here:
https://github.com/SMFSW/vbOffice

The "paragraphs" script will be extended and reworked soon.
Here is the actual code for it:

```vb
' paragraphs
' Get headings and build a table with text, line numbers, paragraph number & depth
' Version: 0.4
' Author: SMFSW, 2016
' Copyright: MIT
'

' TODO: Being able to handle modifications tracking (no count of deleted titles)
' TODO: Find the end of document another way (script may not work on some messy documents)
' TODO: Find a way to handle next heading find not going forward sometimes (which causes end of script)



' par (x, 0) : line in paragraph scale (full line to dot & carriage return / aka paragraph for Word)
' par (x, 1) : pargraph numbering output as string
' par (x, 2) : depth of heading
' par (x, 3) : text of heading
Private par(500, 3) As Variant
Private parCpt As Integer
Private parInit As Boolean


' erase content of global variables & array
Public Sub parErase()
    For i = 0 To 500
        For j = 0 To 3
            par(i, j) = ""
        Next j
    Next i
    parCpt = 0
    parInit = False
End Sub


' return paragraph number of range r
Public Function parGetNum(r As Range) As Double
    Dim rParagraphs As Range
    Dim CurPos As Double
    'If parInit = False Then Call parBuild  ' par tab not needed in parGetNum

    r.Select
    CurPos = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("\startOfSel").Start
    Set rParagraphs = ActiveDocument.Range(Start:=0, End:=CurPos)
    parGetNum = rParagraphs.paragraphs.Count    ' USE NAME OF THE FUNCTION AS RETURN VALUE
End Function


' return paragraph number of range r as formated string
Public Function parGetStr(r As Range) As String
    Dim CurPos As Double
    Dim tmp As String: tmp = ""
    If parInit = False Then Call parBuild

    r.Select
    CurPos = parGetNum(r)
    For j = 0 To parCpt
        If par(j, 0) >= CurPos Then
            If j <> 0 Then
                tmp = par(j - 1, 1)
            Else
                tmp = 0 ' If before 1st Header, return 0
            End If

            Exit For    ' Exit when found
        End If
    Next j
    parGetStr = tmp
End Function


' add par table in a new document
Public Sub parDraw()
    Dim txtHeaders As Variant
    txtHeaders = Array("line", _
                       "chapter", _
                       "depth", _
                       "txt")

    savePerfContext ActiveDocument
    If parInit = False Then Call parBuild
    Call tabBuild(4, 0, par, txtHeaders)
    restorePerfContext ActiveDocument
End Sub


Private Sub parBuild()
    Dim maxDepth As Integer
    Dim cpt As Integer

    Dim flag As Boolean: flag = True
    Dim memStr As String

    ' parInit set to True before everything else so next calls to parGetXXX will not call parBuild again
    parInit = True

    ' move to the first heading (to determine text to strip for title depth)
    Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToHeading, Which:=wdGoToFirst
    Selection.StartOf Unit:=wdParagraph
    Selection.MoveEnd Unit:=wdParagraph

    ' find how is called Title in your Word application
    Dim splt
    splt = split(Selection.Range.Style.NameLocal, " ")
    stripHeader = splt(0)
    Erase splt  ' erase temporary var splt

    ' move back to the start of the document
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory

    'loop until the end of the document is reached
    parCpt = 0
    While flag = True
        Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToHeading, Which:=wdGoToNext
        Selection.StartOf Unit:=wdParagraph
        Selection.MoveEnd Unit:=wdParagraph

        'get the line data
        strLine = Selection.Range.Text

        'check if the end of the document has been reached
        If memStr Like strLine Then flag = False
        memStr = strLine

        par(parCpt, 0) = parGetNum(Selection.Range)
        par(parCpt, 1) = "" ' init to empty str for later loop
        par(parCpt, 2) = Val(Replace(Selection.Range.Style.NameLocal, stripHeader, ""))
        par(parCpt, 3) = strLine

        ' Determining max depth of titles for later
        If par(parCpt, 2) > maxDepth Then maxDepth = par(parCpt, 0)

        ' Handling junk lines
        If parCpt <> 0 Then
            ' if depth par n-1 is equal to n's & line number from n-1 is right before n's
            If par(parCpt - 1, 2) = par(parCpt, 2) And par(parCpt - 1, 0) + 1 = par(parCpt, 0) Then
                ' copy to n-1 & don't incr parCpt
                par(parCpt - 1, 0) = par(parCpt, 0)
                par(parCpt - 1, 1) = par(parCpt, 1)
                par(parCpt - 1, 2) = par(parCpt, 2)
                par(parCpt - 1, 3) = par(parCpt, 3)
            Else: parCpt = parCpt + 1
            End If
        Else: parCpt = parCpt + 1
        End If
    Wend

    For i = 1 To maxDepth                   ' Applying paragraph numbers depth by depth
        cpt = 0                                 ' init at 0 so turns to 1 first time, which is what needed
        For j = 0 To parCpt
            If i > par(j, 2) Then cpt = 0           ' a sub paragraph end reached (resetting current and follow)
            If i = par(j, 2) Then cpt = cpt + 1     ' a new paragraph is reached (increment current and follow)
            If i <= par(j, 2) Then                  ' paragraph depth need to be added to sting
                If i <> 1 Then par(j, 1) = par(j, 1) & "."      ' dot added only if sub paragraph
                par(j, 1) = par(j, 1) & cpt                     ' append paragraph number to string in tab
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Note, in Sept 2023:
I encountered this question while having a lot of trouble with the `range.ListFormat.*` properties. In my case, I was not working with a Selection from an already-open document.  Instead I was using VBA to open a new document from a .dotx template, and then scanning through the paragraphs, such as:

```
 Dim mydoc as document
 Dim x_para as Paragraph
 Dim x_range as Range
 Set mydoc = Documents.Add(Template:="mytemplate.dotx")
 for each x_para in mydoc.Paragraphs
  set x_range = x_para.Range
  'do stuff
 next x_para
```

if I tried to use properties like `x_range.ListFormat.ListString`, or even `x_range.Style` in the "do stuff" loop, I wasn't getting the right data.  The ranges would report their text and some of their embedded bookmark fields, but not much `ListFormat` stuff.  I found that if, before I tried to loop through the paragraphs, I did something like inserting a list-levelled heading, everything would work fine after that.  When using a Selection, the document is already the Active one, so this doesn't trip up the example answer.  But, if, like me, you were trying this after using VBA to open a document, it seems like you kind of have to "wake up" the VBA automation objects in the document before certain properties work right.  I have not tried to see it this happens if you use a `.dotm` template instead of `.dotx`.